# d3 Checking for Duplicate Nodes before Initialization

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, d3.js, force-layout

I am in a kind of unique predicament. I have a d3 force-graph that has a functionality where JSON**s** are being read in over time. I have a method that reads in the data and pushes the links/nodes into an array which is used for the "updating" of the graph. It looks like this:

```
var edges = [];
var nodes = [];

// pushes the NODE attributes in the JSON to the nodes array.
json.nodes.forEach(function(n) {
    nodes.push({
        data: n.data,
        selected: n.selected,
        removed: n.removed
    });
})

// sets the source and target to use id instead of index
json.edges.forEach(function(e) {
    var sourceNode = nodes.filter(function(n) {
                return n.data.id === e.data.source;
        })[0],
        targetNode = nodes.filter(function(n) {
                return n.data.id === e.data.target;
        })[0];

    // push the EDGE attributes in the JSON to the edges array.
    edges.push({
        source: sourceNode,
        target: targetNode,
        data: e.data
    });
});

force
        .nodes(nodes)
        .links(edges)
```

So the source/target are based off the node's ID.

Now the problem is when the JSON data gets read in sometimes it comes with nodes already in the graph since those nodes are attached to some new nodes coming. The new data links with the new graph completely and works. HOWEVER, the nodes that are duplicates are just left floating. I can't use a function that just checks if the nodes has `weight` because I have a delete functionality which can leave some nodes floating.

Also, if I am just checking the array for duplicates before it gets read into the `force.nodes(nodes).links(edges)` it starts to become slow since you are always checking all of the nodes (for the ID). I was wondering if there is a way to check it before its pushed to the graph?

The solution I was thinking of was using a map instead of an array but I am not sure how to make it just check for uniqueness based on d.data['id'] and I am not sure how to `put` into a map with the attributes I have. I tried doing this by...

```
var nodes = {};

// pushes the NODE attributes in the JSON to the nodes MAP.
json.nodes.forEach(function(n) {
    nodes[n.data['id']] = {
        data: n.data,
        selected: n.selected,
        removed: n.removed
    }
})
```

but that errors out. Any assistance on my approach or the right approach on how to do this?

Updated code snippet:

```
var edges = [];
var nodes = [];
var nodesHash = {};

// pushes the NODE attributes in the JSON to the nodes array.
json.nodes.forEach(function(n) {
    nodesHash[n.data['id']] = n;
    if (n.data['id'] in nodesHash) {
        console.log("test break")
        console.log(nodesHash);
        nodes.push({
            data: n.data,
            selected: n.selected,
            removed: n.removed
        });
    }
})

// sets the source and target to use id instead of index
json.edges.forEach(function(e) {
    var sourceNode = nodes.filter(function(n) {
                return n.data.id === e.data.source;
        })[0],
        targetNode = nodes.filter(function(n) {
                return n.data.id === e.data.target;
        })[0];

    // push the EDGE attributes in the JSON to the edges array.
    edges.push({
        source: sourceNode,
        target: targetNode,
        data: e.data
    });
});

force
        .nodes(nodes)
        .links(edges)
```

This still generates the duplicate nodes but the `console.logs` are displaying something like.

```
test break
Object {idfoo: Object}
test break
Object {idfoo: Object, idbar: Object}
test break
Object {idfoo: Object, idbar: Object, idbash: Object}
test break
```

and if you expand on the first `Object {idfoo: Object}` inside it already contains a list of all the node IDs (idfoo, idbar, idbash).

But lets say the next JSON comes and goes through that process. It will but append so for example 2 more nodes come in...

```
Object {idfoo: Object, idbar: Object, idbash: Object, idnext: Object}
test break
Object {idfoo: Object, idbar: Object, idbash: Object, idfoo: Object, idnext: Object}
test break
```

Notice that idfoo is there twice. But if you expand the last `Object {idfoo: Object, idbar: Object, idbash: Object, idfoo: Object, idnext: Object}` then in that list it won't contain 2 idfoo.

Comment: Seems like your hash map approach is the correct way to go, but I think you'd want to use that as a way to *canonicalize* nodes — ie to have a mapping from an id to the one and only node that has that id. So writing to the hash should be as simple as `nodesHash[n.data['id']] = n`. Then when processing incoming links, you'd just look in `nodesHash` for an existing node with that id and, if it exists, swap it in as the `source` or `target` of the new link. Note that `nodesHash` and `nodesArray` should have exactly the same members. The former just provides a performant way to look them up.

Comment: So let's say I create a `nodesHash = {}` and then I have `nodesHash[n.data['id']] = n`. in my `json.nodes.forEach`. If I put the whole `nodes.push` code inside an `if (!(n.data['id'] in nodesHash)) {` I get a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null` and the graph does not load.

Comment: That error is coming from somewhere further downstream, probably when it renders nodes. It may well be caused by a problem with the logic that maintains nodes across updates, but it's nearly impossible to diagnose any of this without a full working version, ideally a fiddle.

Comment: I am having an issue getting my code to work in fiddle, however, I took away the `!` so now it runs with no errors. But, when receiving the next JSON data it still renders the duplicate nodes. I have updated my question with an updated snippet and a sample of the log output which may add some clarification to what is happening.